# Jboss error: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: rest, jersey, jboss7.x

I know this is a general question and it is already answered but those answers are not helping for this case.

I am getting this error in **only** Jboss7.1 final release not in Tomcat(working fine with tomcat version 7) (checked with the same WAR file)

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1300)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
```

### web.xml

```
<display-name>myj2ee.app</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>myj2ee.app</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

### pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### REST Resource class

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) { 
        String output = "Jersey say : " + msg; 
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 
    }

}
```

**Note:**
I have removed the Restlet from Jboss.as standalone config otherwise it gives different error.

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: what is the package name of your service class ?

Comment: I have the same problem, but with JBoss 7.2. Any help/tips/hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: I solved the problem with the answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992320/deploying-a-jersey-1-11-restful-web-service-in-jboss-6-1-final-resteasy-already