# Jersey:The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes(where is it pointing?))

Tags: web-services, rest, jboss

I have defined the webservice like

```
package test.webservice;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {  

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I am deploying my application on jboss. The webservice goes into .war files WEB-INF/lib/webservices.jar, i have verified that my HellowWorldResources class is present in compiled jar. 
My web.xml contains following configuration.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>test.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when i try to access my service like hostname:port/**contextRoot**/rest/helloworld i get com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes. I have gone through many links and tried many options but not getting it right. can any one please point what am i missing? IS there any way, i can log for where is Resource Config pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution for above problem via just removing the below block

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>test.webservice</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and allowing the jersey container to figure out the classes that contains root resources from my WEB-INF. Keeping context-param of removing resteasy (bundled with Jboss) was mandatory for me for avoiding classloader conflict.

Comment: Please see the answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992320/deploying-a-jersey-1-11-restful-web-service-in-jboss-6-1-final-resteasy-already